# Multivariate t-distribution with different degrees of freedom per dimension

Tags: t-distribution, multivariate-distribution

One way to define the multivariate t-distribution is:
$ p(x | \mu, \Sigma, n) = c \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \left(x -\mu\right)^T\Sigma^{-1}\left(x-\mu \right)\right)^\frac{-(n+K)}{2}$ with $K$ the number of Dimensions, a mean vector $\mu$, a correlation matrix $\Sigma$, and some constant $c$ ensuring it integrates to one.

In this case the degrees of freedom $n$ is a scalar and equal for every dimension. I was wondering if there exists a formulation, where the degrees of freedom may be set individually for every dimension, in order to gain more flexibility.

Comment: For that degree of flexibility it would be natural to use a multivariate [copula](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula) with specified margins.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does this multivariate copula still have a parametric form? On a first glance, it looks like a quite complex topic. Could you provide some more details on how to choose the marginals and which copula to use?

Comment: I'm hoping people will provide those details--or other ideas altogether--in answers. As far as copulas go, you can parameterize them easily; there are many choices of families.  For instance, you could even use a copula determined by a particular multivariate T distribution: in effect that would give you a comparable covariance structure but also the ability to tweak the DF in the marginal distributions.  [Nelsen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387286594) is a great place to learn more about copulas.

Comment: I don't understand the assertion that modeling individual "degree of freedom" parameters needs to occur inside the multivariate copula. The marginal distribution' job's are to map the sample values uniformly to the [0,1] interval. If the marginal distributions are truly differing in the "dof" parameter, there is no way to recover the the joint distribution with the copula if you have messed up the marginals to begin with by assuming the same "dof" parameter for each. Something I'm missing?